# Can not identify a name for a combined radio button and checkbox HTML form element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm Trying to create a html form element that is sort of a combination of a radio button and checkbox:

```
o - option 1
o - option 2
o - other options
  ■ - sub option 1
  ■ - sub option 2
```

The idea is that the sub options become available if the parent "other" is chosen"

I'm sure there's a name for this sort of an input method an possibly even jQuery libraries, but unfortunately I am not even able to find out a name to google it by.

Hope someone can help.

Alari

Comment: I think you need conditional form fields, check this out http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Conditional-Form-Fields-conditionize-js.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't get hung up on the name - the problem is trivial enough that it doesn't need one.

You just need to catch the `change` event on the radio buttons, and set the `disabled` property on the checkboxes accordingly, e.g.:

```
$('#radioboxes input[type=radio]').on('change', function() {
    $('#checkboxes input').prop('disabled', this.value != 3);
});
```

(assumes that the radio boxes are all contained inside a `radiogroup` with ID `radioboxes`, and the checkboxes inside a container element such as a div with ID `checkboxes`, per http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/ujyu4tkx/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Why I was hung up on a name was because I'm trying to achieve this for Drupal fields and wanted to be able to search for helpful modules or ideas. I'll do it with a custom module this way and use 2 separate fields :)

Comment: @AlariTruuts you have to use separate fields anyway, there's no such thing as a combined checkbox/radio button in HTML.